# recursive boolean method to check order in rows and columns

Tags: java

I am trying to do a boolean recursive method in java that test if all rows from int[][] m are in order as same as columns.
The only require is that m must be a square matrix.
Example:

1 2 6

2 5 7

4 8 9

thanks

Comment: You should go through the Tour and read the Help Center.

Comment: And what are your current results of your *trying*?

Comment: You simply want to make sure the numbers are in sequential order?

Comment: @Tom It's always false

Comment: @imbcosta does it have to be recursion? A nested for loop should make sure its sequential.

Comment: @lacraig2 yes, but needs to a recursive one

Comment: No one  can help you with your code if you won't add it to your question. Please read [this about asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this about formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @imbcosta is the problem to check individual rows? as in for one row 1,2,3 and then the next row 32,43,59 as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

To use recursion for this problem you must check iterate through the array and check for a condition.

```
static int[][] q;

public static boolean check(int a, int b, int last) {
    if (b >= (q.length - 1) && a >= (q[0].length - 1)){
        if (q[a][b] < last)
            return true;   //last element
        else
            return false;  //last element false!
    }
    if (b == (q.length - 1))   //check if at end of row
        return check(a + 1, 0, 0);  //start at 0 for last and 0 for b, iterate a
    if (q[a][b] <= last)    //check condition (q[a][b] <= last) returns false
        return false;
    return check(a, b + 1, q[a][b]); //check next element
}
```

this will check if its at its limits, check if a condition is met and then iterate. I believe that it will also work for an array of any size. Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. What should be the initial value of `limit`?

Comment: check(0,0,0) in the main method.

Comment: Returns `false` for OPs example.

Comment: Well, there is no edit on that question and it doesn't matter. His example matches the requirement and should return `true`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72882/discussion-between-lacraig2-and-tom).

Comment: Thanks ... First i will try understand your code first and after test it.